# How to put validation to check whether it has data or not? android studio with sqlite

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I'm wondering how to put validation to check if there is "database column1" then whatever I type and save. It will turn to 'Update' instead of creating a new "Column2".

**Here is the code**

```
sB_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            SettingModel txn = new SettingModel();  // initialize your model class first
            txn.setH1(h1.getText().toString());
            txn.setH2(h2.getText().toString());
            txn.setH3(h3.getText().toString());
            txn.setH4(h4.getText().toString());
            txn.setPerson_Charge(Person_Charge.getText().toString());
            txn.setUnit_Code(unit_Code.getText().toString());
            try {
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("header1", txn.getH1());  // get the entered name here.
                cv.put("header2", txn.getH2());
                cv.put("header3", txn.getH3());
                cv.put("header4", txn.getH4());
                cv.put("unitcode", txn.getUnit_Code());
                cv.put("personInCharge", txn.getPerson_Charge());
                db.insert("Information", null, cv);
                db.close();
                Toast.makeText(Setting_Page.this, "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

It needs 'if statement' , But I don't know how to put validation to check... Please Help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you want to update data if data or same primary id exits write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SettingModel txn = new SettingModel();  // initialize your model class first
        txn.setH1(h1.getText().toString());
        txn.setH2(h2.getText().toString());
        txn.setH3(h3.getText().toString());
        txn.setH4(h4.getText().toString());
        txn.setPerson_Charge(Person_Charge.getText().toString());
        txn.setUnit_Code(unit_Code.getText().toString());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query("Information",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        int rowcount = csr.getCount();
        csr.close();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("header1", txn.getH1());  // get the entered name here.
        cv.put("header2", txn.getH2());
        cv.put("header3", txn.getH3());
        cv.put("header4", txn.getH4());
        cv.put("unitcode", txn.getUnit_Code());
        cv.put("personInCharge", txn.getPerson_Charge());
        if (rowcount == 0) {
            db.insert("Information", null, cv);
            Toast.makeText(Setting_Page.this, "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            db.update("Information",cv,null,null);
            Toast.makeText(Setting_Page.this, "Updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

- Note the above is in-principle code and hasn't been tested so may contain errors.

---

An alternative method (perhaps some would say the correct method) would be to create a UNIQUE (index) constraint on a column or columns and then use the **`insertWithonConflict`** with **CONFLICT_REPLACE** (this is the equivalent of the `SQL INSERT OR REPLACE .......`).

Comment: I've tried the Option 2's code. But what I want is only one record('column1'), and whatever I type and change will 'Update' the ('column1').  So means it needs to check if column1 ID is existing then 'update' , if there doesn't exist 'insert'. I don't know whether this logic is correct or not, but this is what I could think of, Only don't know how to change it to code...

Comment: Altered accordingly.

Comment: Noted. Thank you @MikeT